# Regex - How to find file in dynamic folder name

Tags: regex, kettle, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

Is it possible to find file where the folder that I looking to is dynamic using regex?

Path:

```
Folder/Folder/file
```

And the folder is name by year and month number.

E.g:

```
2018/10/File
2018/09/File
2018/01/File
2017/10/File
```

What I want is to find the file with condition is:

```
[CurrentYear]/[CurrentMonth]/File
[CurrentYear]/[LastMonth]/File
```

This thing is run in pentaho using Get File Name/Text File Input Step.

Or any other way to do it?

Assume current date is October 2018.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to get the filename from a path like that?

Comment: @Mark yes, try to learn Pentaho with regex etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to find some RegExp for that, but you can also build this dynamic path in a previous KTR and pass it as a variable to execute.

With the formula step you have date methods which you can extract information, and use calculator step to alter them. For example, you could use a formula step to get TODAY(), and use a calculator step to generate older/future dates, and extract the YEAR(), MONTH(), DAY() from those.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transformation>
  <info>
    <name>Range_of_dates</name>
    <description/>
    <extended_description/>
    <trans_version/>
    <trans_type>Normal</trans_type>
    <directory>&#x2f;</directory>
    <parameters>
    </parameters>
    <log>
      <trans-log-table>
        <connection/>
        <schema/>
        <table/>
        <size_limit_lines/>
        <interval/>
        <timeout_days/>
        <field>
          <id>ID_BATCH</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>ID_BATCH</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>CHANNEL_ID</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>CHANNEL_ID</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>TRANSNAME</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>TRANSNAME</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>STATUS</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>STATUS</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_READ</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_READ</name>
          <subject/>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_WRITTEN</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_WRITTEN</name>
          <subject/>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_UPDATED</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_UPDATED</name>
          <subject/>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_INPUT</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_INPUT</name>
          <subject/>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_OUTPUT</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_OUTPUT</name>
          <subject/>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_REJECTED</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_REJECTED</name>
          <subject/>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>ERRORS</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>ERRORS</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>STARTDATE</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>STARTDATE</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>ENDDATE</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>ENDDATE</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LOGDATE</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LOGDATE</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>DEPDATE</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>DEPDATE</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>REPLAYDATE</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>REPLAYDATE</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LOG_FIELD</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LOG_FIELD</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>EXECUTING_SERVER</id>
          <enabled>N</enabled>
          <name>EXECUTING_SERVER</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>EXECUTING_USER</id>
          <enabled>N</enabled>
          <name>EXECUTING_USER</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>CLIENT</id>
          <enabled>N</enabled>
          <name>CLIENT</name>
        </field>
      </trans-log-table>
      <perf-log-table>
        <connection/>
        <schema/>
        <table/>
        <interval/>
        <timeout_days/>
        <field>
          <id>ID_BATCH</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>ID_BATCH</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>SEQ_NR</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>SEQ_NR</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LOGDATE</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LOGDATE</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>TRANSNAME</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>TRANSNAME</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>STEPNAME</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>STEPNAME</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>STEP_COPY</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>STEP_COPY</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_READ</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_READ</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_WRITTEN</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_WRITTEN</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_UPDATED</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_UPDATED</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_INPUT</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_INPUT</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_OUTPUT</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_OUTPUT</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_REJECTED</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_REJECTED</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>ERRORS</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>ERRORS</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>INPUT_BUFFER_ROWS</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>INPUT_BUFFER_ROWS</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>OUTPUT_BUFFER_ROWS</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>OUTPUT_BUFFER_ROWS</name>
        </field>
      </perf-log-table>
      <channel-log-table>
        <connection/>
        <schema/>
        <table/>
        <timeout_days/>
        <field>
          <id>ID_BATCH</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>ID_BATCH</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>CHANNEL_ID</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>CHANNEL_ID</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LOG_DATE</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LOG_DATE</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LOGGING_OBJECT_TYPE</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LOGGING_OBJECT_TYPE</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>OBJECT_NAME</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>OBJECT_NAME</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>OBJECT_COPY</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>OBJECT_COPY</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>REPOSITORY_DIRECTORY</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>REPOSITORY_DIRECTORY</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>FILENAME</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>FILENAME</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>OBJECT_ID</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>OBJECT_ID</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>OBJECT_REVISION</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>OBJECT_REVISION</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>PARENT_CHANNEL_ID</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>PARENT_CHANNEL_ID</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>ROOT_CHANNEL_ID</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>ROOT_CHANNEL_ID</name>
        </field>
      </channel-log-table>
      <step-log-table>
        <connection/>
        <schema/>
        <table/>
        <timeout_days/>
        <field>
          <id>ID_BATCH</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>ID_BATCH</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>CHANNEL_ID</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>CHANNEL_ID</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LOG_DATE</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LOG_DATE</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>TRANSNAME</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>TRANSNAME</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>STEPNAME</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>STEPNAME</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>STEP_COPY</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>STEP_COPY</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_READ</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_READ</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_WRITTEN</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_WRITTEN</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_UPDATED</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_UPDATED</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_INPUT</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_INPUT</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_OUTPUT</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_OUTPUT</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_REJECTED</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_REJECTED</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>ERRORS</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>ERRORS</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LOG_FIELD</id>
          <enabled>N</enabled>
          <name>LOG_FIELD</name>
        </field>
      </step-log-table>
      <metrics-log-table>
        <connection/>
        <schema/>
        <table/>
        <timeout_days/>
        <field>
          <id>ID_BATCH</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>ID_BATCH</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>CHANNEL_ID</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>CHANNEL_ID</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LOG_DATE</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LOG_DATE</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>METRICS_DATE</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>METRICS_DATE</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>METRICS_CODE</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>METRICS_CODE</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>METRICS_DESCRIPTION</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>METRICS_DESCRIPTION</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>METRICS_SUBJECT</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>METRICS_SUBJECT</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>METRICS_TYPE</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>METRICS_TYPE</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>METRICS_VALUE</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>METRICS_VALUE</name>
        </field>
      </metrics-log-table>
    </log>
    <maxdate>
      <connection/>
      <table/>
      <field/>
      <offset>0.0</offset>
      <maxdiff>0.0</maxdiff>
    </maxdate>
    <size_rowset>10000</size_rowset>
    <sleep_time_empty>50</sleep_time_empty>
    <sleep_time_full>50</sleep_time_full>
    <unique_connections>N</unique_connections>
    <feedback_shown>Y</feedback_shown>
    <feedback_size>50000</feedback_size>
    <using_thread_priorities>Y</using_thread_priorities>
    <shared_objects_file/>
    <capture_step_performance>N</capture_step_performance>
    <step_performance_capturing_delay>1000</step_performance_capturing_delay>
    <step_performance_capturing_size_limit>100</step_performance_capturing_size_limit>
    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>
    <partitionschemas>
    </partitionschemas>
    <slaveservers>
    </slaveservers>
    <clusterschemas>
    </clusterschemas>
    <created_user>-</created_user>
    <created_date>2018&#x2f;10&#x2f;26 11&#x3a;34&#x3a;38.865</created_date>
    <modified_user>-</modified_user>
    <modified_date>2018&#x2f;10&#x2f;26 11&#x3a;34&#x3a;38.865</modified_date>
    <key_for_session_key/>
    <is_key_private>N</is_key_private>
  </info>
  <notepads>
  </notepads>
  <order>
    <hop>
      <from>Generate Rows</from>
      <to>Add sequence</to>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
    </hop>
    <hop>
      <from>Add sequence</from>
      <to>Today</to>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
    </hop>
    <hop>
      <from>Today</from>
      <to>Today - Number</to>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
    </hop>
    <hop>
      <from>Today - Number</from>
      <to>Parts of the Date</to>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
    </hop>
    <hop>
      <from>Parts of the Date</from>
      <to>2 Digit Month and Day</to>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
    </hop>
    <hop>
      <from>2 Digit Month and Day</from>
      <to>Copy rows to result</to>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
    </hop>
  </order>
  <step>
    <name>Generate Rows</name>
    <type>RowGenerator</type>
    <description/>
    <distribute>Y</distribute>
    <custom_distribution/>
    <copies>1</copies>
    <partitioning>
      <method>none</method>
      <schema_name/>
    </partitioning>
    <fields>
    </fields>
    <limit>60</limit>
    <never_ending>N</never_ending>
    <interval_in_ms>5000</interval_in_ms>
    <row_time_field>now</row_time_field>
    <last_time_field>FiveSecondsAgo</last_time_field>
    <cluster_schema/>
    <remotesteps>
      <input>
      </input>
      <output>
      </output>
    </remotesteps>
    <GUI>
      <xloc>48</xloc>
      <yloc>32</yloc>
      <draw>Y</draw>
    </GUI>
    </step>

  <step>
    <name>Add sequence</name>
    <type>Sequence</type>
    <description/>
    <distribute>Y</distribute>
    <custom_distribution/>
    <copies>1</copies>
    <partitioning>
      <method>none</method>
      <schema_name/>
    </partitioning>
      <valuename>valuename</valuename>
      <use_database>N</use_database>
      <connection/>
      <schema/>
      <seqname>SEQ_</seqname>
      <use_counter>Y</use_counter>
      <counter_name/>
      <start_at>-1</start_at>
      <increment_by>-1</increment_by>
      <max_value>999999999</max_value>
    <cluster_schema/>
    <remotesteps>
      <input>
      </input>
      <output>
      </output>
    </remotesteps>
    <GUI>
      <xloc>160</xloc>
      <yloc>32</yloc>
      <draw>Y</draw>
    </GUI>
    </step>

  <step>
    <name>Today</name>
    <type>Formula</type>
    <description/>
    <distribute>Y</distribute>
    <custom_distribution/>
    <copies>1</copies>
    <partitioning>
      <method>none</method>
      <schema_name/>
    </partitioning>
       <formula><field_name>today</field_name>
<formula_string>TODAY&#x28;&#x29;</formula_string>
<value_type>Date</value_type>
<value_length>-1</value_length>
<value_precision>-1</value_precision>
<replace_field/>
</formula>
    <cluster_schema/>
    <remotesteps>
      <input>
      </input>
      <output>
      </output>
    </remotesteps>
    <GUI>
      <xloc>256</xloc>
      <yloc>32</yloc>
      <draw>Y</draw>
    </GUI>
    </step>

  <step>
    <name>Today - Number</name>
    <type>Calculator</type>
    <description/>
    <distribute>Y</distribute>
    <custom_distribution/>
    <copies>1</copies>
    <partitioning>
      <method>none</method>
      <schema_name/>
    </partitioning>
    <calculation>
      <field_name>date_minus_days</field_name>
      <calc_type>ADD_DAYS</calc_type>
      <field_a>today</field_a>
      <field_b>valuename</field_b>
      <field_c/>
      <value_type>Date</value_type>
      <value_length>-1</value_length>
      <value_precision>-1</value_precision>
      <remove>N</remove>
      <conversion_mask>yyyy&#x2f;MM&#x2f;dd</conversion_mask>
      <decimal_symbol/>
      <grouping_symbol/>
      <currency_symbol/>
    </calculation>
    <cluster_schema/>
    <remotesteps>
      <input>
      </input>
      <output>
      </output>
    </remotesteps>
    <GUI>
      <xloc>352</xloc>
      <yloc>32</yloc>
      <draw>Y</draw>
    </GUI>
    </step>

  <step>
    <name>Parts of the Date</name>
    <type>Formula</type>
    <description/>
    <distribute>Y</distribute>
    <custom_distribution/>
    <copies>1</copies>
    <partitioning>
      <method>none</method>
      <schema_name/>
    </partitioning>
       <formula><field_name>Year</field_name>
<formula_string>YEAR&#x28;&#x5b;date_minus_days&#x5d;&#x29;</formula_string>
<value_type>Integer</value_type>
<value_length>-1</value_length>
<value_precision>-1</value_precision>
<replace_field/>
</formula>
       <formula><field_name>Month</field_name>
<formula_string>MONTH&#x28;&#x5b;date_minus_days&#x5d;&#x29;</formula_string>
<value_type>Integer</value_type>
<value_length>-1</value_length>
<value_precision>-1</value_precision>
<replace_field/>
</formula>
       <formula><field_name>Day</field_name>
<formula_string>DAY&#x28;&#x5b;date_minus_days&#x5d;&#x29;</formula_string>
<value_type>Integer</value_type>
<value_length>-1</value_length>
<value_precision>-1</value_precision>
<replace_field/>
</formula>
    <cluster_schema/>
    <remotesteps>
      <input>
      </input>
      <output>
      </output>
    </remotesteps>
    <GUI>
      <xloc>464</xloc>
      <yloc>32</yloc>
      <draw>Y</draw>
    </GUI>
    </step>

  <step>
    <name>2 Digit Month and Day</name>
    <type>SelectValues</type>
    <description/>
    <distribute>Y</distribute>
    <custom_distribution/>
    <copies>1</copies>
    <partitioning>
      <method>none</method>
      <schema_name/>
    </partitioning>
    <fields>        <select_unspecified>N</select_unspecified>
      <meta>        <name>Month</name>
        <rename>Month</rename>
        <type>String</type>
        <length>-2</length>
        <precision>-2</precision>
        <conversion_mask>00</conversion_mask>
        <date_format_lenient>false</date_format_lenient>
        <date_format_locale/>
        <date_format_timezone/>
        <lenient_string_to_number>false</lenient_string_to_number>
        <encoding/>
        <decimal_symbol/>
        <grouping_symbol/>
        <currency_symbol/>
        <storage_type/>
      </meta>      <meta>        <name>Day</name>
        <rename>Day</rename>
        <type>String</type>
        <length>-2</length>
        <precision>-2</precision>
        <conversion_mask>00</conversion_mask>
        <date_format_lenient>false</date_format_lenient>
        <date_format_locale/>
        <date_format_timezone/>
        <lenient_string_to_number>false</lenient_string_to_number>
        <encoding/>
        <decimal_symbol/>
        <grouping_symbol/>
        <currency_symbol/>
        <storage_type/>
      </meta>    </fields>    <cluster_schema/>
    <remotesteps>
      <input>
      </input>
      <output>
      </output>
    </remotesteps>
    <GUI>
      <xloc>592</xloc>
      <yloc>32</yloc>
      <draw>Y</draw>
    </GUI>
    </step>

  <step>
    <name>Copy rows to result</name>
    <type>RowsToResult</type>
    <description/>
    <distribute>Y</distribute>
    <custom_distribution/>
    <copies>1</copies>
    <partitioning>
      <method>none</method>
      <schema_name/>
    </partitioning>
    <cluster_schema/>
    <remotesteps>
      <input>
      </input>
      <output>
      </output>
    </remotesteps>
    <GUI>
      <xloc>720</xloc>
      <yloc>32</yloc>
      <draw>Y</draw>
    </GUI>
    </step>

  <step_error_handling>
  </step_error_handling>
  <slave-step-copy-partition-distribution>
  </slave-step-copy-partition-distribution>
  <slave_transformation>N</slave_transformation>
</transformation>
```

You can save this snippet to a .ktr file and open in PDI Spoon.

After this, you need a Job that executes this first KTR, and passes the result to another, in this second KTR you can access the variables in the Get File Names step like you would any other variable:

**C:\${year}\${month}\File**

Comment: I not understand about xml code, can u explain more specific about your code (step by step)? I have save those code in kettle using `Get Data From XLM` step but I'm not understand what those used for? It's to many field I get from those code, most of them are empty and i'm not sure what should I passes to another transformation.

Comment: Well thanks, because of your answer I get an idea. I do those thing in Job level, using 2 transformation. First transformation is to get year, current month and  last month number by using `Get System Info` step to get current timestamp then use `Calculator` step to extract Integer of year, last month and current month number. The second one is to get the file like your answer using `Get File Names` step with path `C:\${year}\${month}\File`. But please explain about those xml, still curious about it? What for and how to used.

Comment: If you simply copy all that XML and save to a file pentaho.ktr, you can open the transformation in the Spoon GUI. In Pentaho Data Integration all KTRs and all KJBs are an xml, even if you have a DB Repository.